# Totalling up values in a table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-table

After an ajax call, results is returned in success, then:

```
var the_data = results;

var buildHTML = [];

buildHTML.push("<tr><td>Department</td><td>Count</td><td>Value</td>");

for (var i = 0; i < the_data.length; i++) {
    buildHTML.push("<tr><td>" + the_data[i].department + "</td><td>" + the_data[i].count + "</td><td>£" + the_data[i].value + "</td>");
}

$('.portlet-content').empty().append("<table>" + buildHTML.join('</tr>') + "</table>");
```

Which builds something like:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Department
        </td>
        <td>
            Count
        </td>
        <td>
            Value
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Marketing
        </td>
        <td>
            10
        </td>
        <td>
            £100,000
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Information Technology
        </td>
        <td>
            20
        </td>
        <td>
            £1,000,000
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I know how to add another final row at the bottom of this table, but in that row, I want to display totals, i.e. a total of the count and a total of the value, e.g:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Department
        </td>
        <td>
            Count
        </td>
        <td>
            Value
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Marketing
        </td>
        <td>
            10
        </td>
        <td>
            £100,000
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Information Technology
        </td>
        <td>
            20
        </td>
        <td>
            £1,000,000
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Total
        </td>
        <td>
            30
        </td>
        <td>
            £1,100,000
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How can this be done at clientside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply amend the for loop in your code to get the sums.

```
...
// vars for sum
var the_count = 0, the_sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < the_data.length; i++) {
    the_count += the_data[i].count;
    the_sum += the_data[i].value;
    buildHTML.push("<tr><td>" + the_data[i].department + "</td><td>" + the_data[i].count + "</td><td>£" + the_data[i].value + "</td>");
}
buildHTML.push("<tr><td>Total</td><td>" + the_count + "</td><td>" + the_sum + "</td>");
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generic solution that will work for any table with a tfoot and tbody:

```
$("table tfoot td").each(function(columnIndex) {
    var totalsElement = $(this);

    if (totalsElement.hasClass("sumTotal")) {
        var sum = 0.0;
        totalsElement.parents("table").find("tbody tr").each(function() {
            sum += parseFloat($(this).children("td").eq(columnIndex).html());
        });
        totalsElement.html(sum);
    }
});
```

You need to mark the computed footer cells with "sumTotal" CSS class. To keep it simple I had to remove the pound characters from the table but it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/fRdpJ/47/

Answer (score 0):

add a `class="Count"` on the `TD` for which you want to calculate count and then calculate count using JQuery like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/sv2dg/13/